# Split strings by a specific range in R

Tags: r, string, split

I want to split a string object by two strings at a time until they reach the last string.

Suppose you have the string "BANANAS" I want to split the string by two obtaining BA AN NA AN NA AS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be by splitting the string.

```
split_string <- function(x) {
  lapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(x) paste0(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)))  
}
split_string(c('BANANAS', 'APPLE'))

#[[1]]
#[1] "BA" "AN" "NA" "AN" "NA" "AS"

#[[2]]
#[1] "AP" "PP" "PL" "LE"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
split_string <- function(x) {
   lapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) paste0(x[-length(x)], x[-1]))
}
```

-output

```
split_string(v1)
#[[1]]
#[1] "BA" "AN" "NA" "AN" "NA" "AS"

#[[2]]
#[1] "AP" "PP" "PL" "LE"
```

---

Or we can use a regex lookaround without splitting

```
out <- gsub('(?<=.)(.)(?=.)', '\\1 \\1', v1, perl = TRUE)
out
#[1] "BA AN NA AN NA AS" "AP PP PL LE"
```

then if we need individual substring, split by space

```
strsplit(out, "\\s+")
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("BANANAS", "APPLE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> string <- "BANANAS"

> # split and use embed
> x <- embed(str_split(string, '')[[1]], 2)[, 2:1] # reverse columns

> apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = '')
[1] "BA" "AN" "NA" "AN" "NA" "AS"
```